# Powershell: invoke script ignore prompt

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

My question is thus:

lets say in my PS script I am trying to invoke another script like so:

`& $scriptLocation $scriptArgs`

**note** this is all happening in a PSSession.

the execution policy of the remote server is unrestricted, but when my script attempts to execute the other, I get prompted to confirm I want to execute it. How do I avoid this prompt?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the script in `$scriptLocation` [Unblocked](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849924%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)? Do you need a `-Confirm:$false` somewhere?

Comment: I'd check if the script is "Unblocked" (you can right-click on the script and check for an Unblock button, which indicates that the script is blocked). Faced this issue recently.